# Adding events to caldroid

Tags: android, caldroid

am new to android. am creating a calendar using cal-droid library. I have set of data`s from the server, and I need to highlight those event dates in the calendar and also upon taping on a particular date, display the list of events for that date in list view below calendar view. Could any one please tell me any references or some sample codes for the same using Cal-droid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use predefine method in caldroid Lib make sure you are supplying correct Format

```
dialogCaldroidFragment.setSelectedDates(formatter.parse("yourfromdate"),
formatter.parse("yourtodate"));
```

or use    `dialogCaldroidFragment.setBackgroundResourceForDates(formatter.parse("yourfromdate"));`

link : https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid/issues/34

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But my questions is how to add events for a particular date and how to high light that date ?

Comment: I have tried the following code caldroidFragment.setSelectedDate(date); but still date is not highlighting